# Conditional formatting if a datetime value is present in a list of datetime values

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to compare two lists of DateTime values in a Google Sheets. I want to highlight all DateTimes in the first list which are also present in the second list.

I already tried to use `MATCH()`, `COUNTIF()`, `FILTER()` together with `COUNTA()` or other approaches. However, although the values in both lists are basically copies of each other (just with some missing values in the second list), no matches will be returned. All are "true" DateTime values which can be formatted by using any of the date and time formatting options.

The MATCH example:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,INDIRECT("OTHERSHEET!$A$2:$A"),0))
```

I assume that there might be differences in the DateTime interpretation in the comparison why I also tried to use `N()` without success. I will always get an error like `Did not find value '43297.75867' in MATCH evaluation.` respectively `FALSE` after the `ISNUMBER()`.

If I just do something like `=N(A1)=N(OTHERSHEET!A1)` with matching DateTimes, I get `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **custom formula:** **`=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,INDIRECT("OTHERSHEET!$A$1:$A"),0))`**

> [image: 2]
>
> [image: 1]

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. Afterwards, I noticed, that my formula was already working but only for the first few hundred rows of the sheet. It might be a bug for larger sheets as about 2000 rows need to be compared for each individual row. This seems to fail at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Same principle, but shorter:

```
=MATCH(A1,INDIRECT("OTHERSHEET!A:A"),0)
```